# The requested resource(/solr/update) is not available

Tags: solr

I have deployed solr 3.6.1 in Centos.Now I can search document,But I fail to delete document in solr.

The relevant part of solrconfig.xml like this:

```
  <requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
  </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name="/update/csv" class="solr.CSVRequestHandler" >
     <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="seperator">,</str>
      <str name="header">true</str>
      <str name="encapsulator">"</str>
     </lst>
  </requestHandler>
```

When I enter this url

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/update/?stream.body=<delete><id>123</id></delete>&stream.contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&commit=true
```

in my browser,the result is:

```
type Status report

message: /solr/update

description: The requested resource is not available
```

However, the update/csv handler works fine.

I'm wondering is there something wrong with the configuration in solrconfig.xml?

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Finally,I find the answer!
when I change the update handler conf to:

```
<requestHandler name="/update" class="solr.XmlUpdateRequestHandler">
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

The example on the Solr Wiki for [UpdateXmlMessages via GET](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#Updating_via_GET) states

> Short update requests can also be sent using a GET request (needs to be url-encoded)

So I would try the following, like the example

```
 http://localhost:8080/solr/update/?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cid%3E123%3C/id%3E%3C/delete%3E
 http://localhost:8080/solr/update/?stream.body=%3Ccommit/%3E
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work,the requested resource is not available

Comment: Hmmm. What is the url that you use for searching?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try update as json;

```
curl 'http://<your_url>/solr/<yourcorename>/update?commit=true' -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '[{"id":"123","field_1":{"set":899.99}, "field_2":{"set":123}}]'
```

id is a must field for update..